# Html <ul> TranslateX

Tags: html, css

i have a ul-Element with 30 li-Elements, but only 20 Elements are shown, the overflow is hidden. Now i want to show the last 20 Elements. Is there a translateY(X)-Method for the ul-Element or something else?

Fesp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is shooting into that big vague question. Hopefully it hits!

```
 <ul id="ul_id" style="height:200px;overflow:hidden;">
      <li></li>
      ...
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('ul_id').scrollTop=150;
 </script>
```

You can scroll a div with "scrollTop" in javascript. Just set the desired offset in pixels.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly, what i was searching. Here it is important to scroll the div and not the ul-Element.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to scroll the element to reveal children that are "below the fold". Depending on if they're stacked on top of each other or in a row you'll need to use ul.scrollTop or ul.scrollLeft (from JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Not a CSS HTML method I know. But the only way I can think to do what you ask (if I'm guessing correctly) is via jQuery, so.....

This will dynamically add an additional li with "See More..." when clicked, it will show more items on the list.

```
$(function() { 
var hiddenStuff = $('.list li:gt(5)').hide();
if (hiddenStuff.size() > 0) {
  var theCaption = '... See More';
  $('.list').append(
      $('<li class="more" id="toggler">' + theCaption + '</li>')
          .toggle( function() { 
              hiddenStuff.slideDown(1000);
              $(this).text('...See Less');
          }, 
          function() { 
              hiddenStuff.slideUp(1000);
              $(this).text(theCaption);
          })
        );
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gTm2p/1/)

A CSS-only solution, which may work for you here: [CSS-ONLY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gTm2p/2/)